# POI 3.17 bold font

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm upgrading from POI 3.15 to 3.17

This code does not compile:

```
HSSFFont fontTitle = wb.createFont();
fontTitle.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
fontTitle.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
```

I've changed to:

```
Font fontTitle = wb.createFont();
fontTitle.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
fontTitle.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
```

but still in error:

```
/excel/SQL2XLSX17N.java:271: cannot find symbol               
symbol  : variable BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD                            
location: interface org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font          
               fontTitle.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
```

How do I use a bold font?

Answer (score 16):

Use `Font.setBold(true)` to embolden.

[Signature](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#setBold-boolean-):

```
void setBold(boolean bold)
```

Answer (score 15):

Just for history:

OLD:  `f.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);`
NEW:  `f.setBold(false);`

OLD: `fb.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);`
NEW: `fb.setBold(true);`

```
/**
 * sets the font to be bold or not
 */
public void setBold(boolean bold) {
    if (bold)
        font.setBoldWeight(BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    else
        font.setBoldWeight(BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me until I changed the method name to setBoldweight() with a lowercase `w`.